# rselenium iterating dropdown menu

Tags: r, rselenium

Sorry i'm really new to coding, but I have my code here and I am trying to change one of my lines of code, line 26, to @value = "11", incrementing up to "20".

```
library(writexl) # convert table into usable excel sheet
library(rvest) # webscrape tables
library(dplyr) #data manipulation
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)
library(data.table)

rs_driver_object <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome",
                             chromever = "103.0.5060.134",
                             verbose = F,
                             port = free_port())

remDr <- rs_driver_object$client


remDr$navigate("https://apps.oirp.ncsu.edu/pgem/index.cfm?action=main.summary")

ncsu_table <-remDr$findElement(using = 'id', 'summaryTable')


college_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//select[@name="collegeID"]')
college_button$clickElement()

next_college <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//select[@name="collegeID"]/option[@value = "11"]')
remDr$mouseMoveToLocation(webElement = next_college)


next_college$clickElement()

update_button <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//input[@id="btnFilter2"]')

update_button$clickElement()
```

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this:

```r
for (i in seq(11, 20)) {
  next_college <- remDr$findElement(using = 'xpath', paste0("//select[@name='collegeID']/option[@value = '", z, "']"))
}
```

Obviously, put the rest of the code that should loop inside of the loop with this part. `paste0` just pastes the iteration value without separation.